# PHP output tag is not working

Tags: php

I installed a new WAMP on my computer (before I used XAMPP - everything was good as I remember). My problem is the php output tag (`<?= ?>`) which is not working (in the browser when I click on show sourcecode it is appears exactly in the file - so it is not processed...)

Am I wrong something? Is there an option in php.ini to turn on this tag? I need this tag.

Code how I tried:

```
<?php
 $examples = "Some text...";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Examples</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Examples</h1>
        <ul>
            <?= $examples ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can turn it on updating the php.ini to allow short tags. Mouseover the PHP menu option in WAMP and look for settings. Set `short_open_tag` to `on`.

Comment: As an aside, starting with PHP 5.4 `<?= ?>` syntax is available regardless of `short_open_tag` being on or off.

Comment: Thanks for the exact setting name. I was doing this from memory and couldn't remember the exact setting name.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your php.ini. But i think it's better to use the classic tags to avoid problem with xml tag